# SELECT Index of an insterted row?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i need to do 2 mysql query:

```
1st- That insert some data into mi database with an autoincreasing Index (managed by mysql)
2nd- I need to use this index into another SELECT query.
```

Now i'm doing:

```
- INSERT INTO .....
- SELECT Index FROM.... (Index of the row just added)
- SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ID=Index
```

Are there any more permormancing solution to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a function to know what was the last id inserted in the current connection

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO FOO(a) VALUES(\'b\')');
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

your sql query will ne now

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ID=$id
```

That function is called [mysql_insert_id](http://fr.php.net/mysql_insert_id)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below one.

INSERT INTO .....
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```